# How to move images to new dynamic folder

Tags: php

Dear friends I have a simple code to move  some images to dynamically created folders
Here is my code

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
include("connection.php");

$sql = "SELECT manufacturers.id, user_profiles.logo
        FROM  `manufacturers` 
        INNER JOIN user_profiles
        WHERE manufacturers.user_id = user_profiles.user_id AND manufacturers.id > 2235";

$query=mysqli_query($live_db, $sql) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error($live_db));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query) ){

    $temp = '/home/aigae4z5r/mydomain.com/frontend/web/uploads/manufacturers/images/'. $row['logo'];

    $idDir = '/home/aigae4z5r/mydomain.com/frontend/web/uploads/manufacturers/'.$id;

    $destinationPath = $idDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $row['logo'];

    if (!is_dir($idDir)) {
        mkdir($idDir, 0777, TRUE);
    }

    if (rename($temp, $destinationPath)) {
        echo 'moved! <br />';
    } else {
        echo 'failed <br />';
    }
}
```

The problem is to create new folders

```
   if (!is_dir($idDir)) {
        mkdir($idDir, 0777, TRUE);
}
```

Comment: **The problem is to create new folders**, and what is the problem ?

Comment: I am unable to create folder, code is not working, I am afraid if there is any permission problem ?

Comment: I cant find `$id` defined in your code

Comment: I guess my variable $id is wrong, it should be $row['id'];

Comment: yes. exactly problem with variable only

Comment: @B.Desai you just fixed my problem Thank you very much sir

Comment: Now directory is working fine, but 90% of my query returns 'failed' response 

    if (rename($temp, $destinationPath)) {
            echo 'moved! <br />';
        } else {
            echo 'failed <br />';
        }

Comment: is there any specific logic behind this ? it moved very few of my images

Comment: This is also fixed I had type varchar 45 in my logo name, I just changed it to 'text' 
everything is fine now :D